# Excel xlsx files downloading as zip file

Tags: excel, apache, .htaccess, internet-explorer-8, zip

The following is happening in IE8.  The server is Apache2 on Ubuntu.

I'm trying to get an excel file to download via a link.  When I click the link the file shows with a .zip extension.

I've set the mime-types in a .htaccess file and also can see they are in the /etc/mime.type file.

The .htaccess file as follows:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12 .docm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document docx
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template dotx
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12 potm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template potx
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12 ppam
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12 ppsm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow ppsx
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12 pptm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation pptx
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12 xlam
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12 xlsb
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12 xlsm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet xlsx
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12 xltm
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template xltx
```

I've looked a loads of forums some say the leading  dot for .docm on the the first line should be added other say not.  The Apache documentation say it can include on not include the leading dot.  I've tried with both.

I've copied the code to a text editor to make sure there are no hidden characters and pasted it back.
I've cleared the browser cache after each change and restarted Apache.  Nothing seems to work.
This did work on our old server so I'm convinced the problem is server configuration.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have since noticed that we have nginx as a reverse proxy, so I have added the mine types to its mime.types file and restarted the server.  This didn't make any difference.

Comment: Finally found the problem.  Nothing to do with the server(s), so the above information is good.  The issue was to do with a Joomla plugin Contentbuilder. I'll post a separate post for that.